# One launch icon per Microsoft Edge profile

Tags: unity

One of the feature of Microsoft Edge I love on windows (probably the same for other chromium products), is the ability to have one taskbar icon for each profile

[image: MS Edge multi profile on windows]

However, using ubuntu, all profiles window are merged in a single app in the unity launcher (one "dot" per window):

[image: MS Edge multi profile in unity]

Is it possible to split the icons like in Windows?